# Automatically create partition by field number every 15 minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi i want create automatically partition based on the a filed number that is a timestamp (every 15 minutes):
for example:

201401010000   <---- 2014 Gen 01 00:00

201401010000 < number < 201401010015   <---- first partition

201401010016 < number < 201401010030   <----second partion
.
.
.

i have seen this code for a date every month:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date) 
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
(  
PARTITION pos_data_p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
PARTITION pos_data_p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-8-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
);
```

but for a number field every 15 minutes??

thanks

Comment: yes every 15 minutes of the TIMESTAMP

Comment: Change the timestamp column data type from number to an actual timestamp and the interval partitioning will work.

Comment: with this code:

CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(   
nome varchar2 (50),
dateins number (15)
);

 ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (start_date_TS  TIMESTAMP(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_timestamp('201410200000', 'yyyymmddhh24mi')));

PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date_TS) 
INTERVAL(INTERVAL '15' MINUTES) 
(  
PARTITION pos_data_inital VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2014-10-20 00:15:00'),
); 

I have error ORA-54012: virtual column is referenced in a column expression. why? thanks for help me

Comment: How many records are inserted into this table every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

You should either change the number type to `TIMESTAMP` or you an add a virtual column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (start_date_TS  TIMESTAMP(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_timestamp(start_date, 'yyyymmddhh24mi')));
```

Then you can use this partitioning clause:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date_TS) 
INTERVAL(INTERVAL '15' MINUTE) 
(  
PARTITION pos_data_inital VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2007-07-01 00:00:00'),
);
```

Here a working example for a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE ( 
    nome VARCHAR2 (50), 
    start_date NUMBER (12) ,
    start_date_TS TIMESTAMP(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(start_date,1,12), 'yyyymmddhh24mi'))
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date_TS) INTERVAL(INTERVAL '15' MINUTE) 
    ( PARTITION pos_data_inital VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2014-10-20 00:15:00') );
```

Comment: I corrected my post, please check